# Spring 4.0 vs Java EE 7

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, spring-4

I have an application using Spring Framework. Now I plan to convert it to web application. The research on Google shows that main competitor to Spring MVC is now Java EE 7. Are there any advantages to move to Java EE 7 instead of Spring?

Please notice, performance is very important for me.

Comment: this kind of questions tends to be prohibited. Any stack will let you create maintainable and fast web apps. Just try avoid using a app server (i.e: glassfish) and add to it spring jars that offer exactly the same functionality.(Classloader Nightmares)

Comment: @Chechus: What kind of advice is that? Yep, this question is not the right format for SO, but telling him to avoid app server is not the best advice when using Java EE...

Comment: @user2924714: I tell you one advantage, Java EE is the standard, Spring is not. But besides that, you can use the framework of your choice, either server-centric or client-centric to write web applications - more important than the choice of framework is you specific use case and your personal experience, now and the plans for it in future.

Comment: @Geziefer Noooo!!!!, is about mixing app servers with spring jars that executes the same functionality, example: add hibernate jars to Glassfish (that uses eclipselink). App servers is the way to go if you are prefer to avoid vendor locking

Comment: @Chechus: Ah ok, then I'm with you.

Comment: If performance is very important and your application is going to handle big number of concurrent connections, you might want to consider https://www.playframework.com/